# How to Read external storage from Android App using dexter?

Tags: java, android, xml, audio-player

Using Dexter to read external storage from my Android App ,but the permission seeking popup does not appear once the app is launched.
Configuration for dexter.

```
        Dexter.withContext(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Runtime Permission given", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                       permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                })
                .check();
```

I have imported android.Manifest.
Here is the change made to AndroidManifest.xml for granting permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

changes made to dependencies in built.gradle

```
 implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
```

I was trying to get a permission seeking popup that would allow my app to seek permission from the user to get access to external storage to display songs from the phone but its not working at all.
Needed this output.[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cRMG.jpg)

Comment: The used permission `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` shows that your code is not usable on Android 11+ as this permission is useless on these versions. As Dexter seems to be a dead project (archived by owner) https://github.com/karumi/Dexter I would recommend to remove that library and migrate to Google's support library AndroidX. Also make yourself familiar with scoped storage.

Comment: @Robert. READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not needed anymore on Android 13+ devices. Of course it is still needed on Android 12- devices.

Comment: OP: There is nothing in your code that tries to read from external storage. So where are you talking about?